# Excel VLOOKUP FUNCTION with multiple lookup values doesn't work

Tags: excel, vlookup

Dear StackOverFlow members,

I am running into a problem using the VLOOKUP FUNCTION in Excel.

I will give a quick overview of the sheets and the corresponding variable names and values:

First sheet:

[image]

Second Sheet:

[image]

In the second sheet the export values of Austria between multiple EU countries has to be pasted in the first sheet in the column of exports, also it must use lookup values of the first sheet based on the variables Country, Counterpart country(Austria) and year.

I have tried using this:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3&B3&C3,'Austr Exp'!A:C,3,FALSE),"")
```

Unfortunately I get a blank cell and it does nothing.

Comment: Since the return value is numeric, use `SUMIFS`.